# How do I get Total sum of a column in Vue JS

Tags: javascript, vue.js

[image: As in the Attached picture it not getting the total right.]

You can add a row manually and each row is in "items" array

```
items: [
  {
    occuGroup:'',
    constType:'',
    bfloorArea: 0,
    cfloorArea: 0
  },
],
```

Here's the code that I wrote to get Total

```
subTotal: function() {
  var total = 0;
  this.items.forEach(element => {
    total += (element.bfloorArea);
  });
  return total;
},
```

How do I get that right? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with your code is you are adding items as a string instead, you need number type.

```
subTotal: function() {
  return this.items.reduce((acc, ele) => {
    return acc + parseInt(ele.bfloorArea);
  }, 0);
},
```

```js
function subTotal(items) {
  return items.reduce((acc, ele) => {
    return acc + parseInt(ele.bfloorArea);
  }, 0);
}

const items = [
  {
    occuGroup: "",
    constType: "",
    bfloorArea: 0,
    cfloorArea: 0,
  },
  {
    occuGroup: "",
    constType: "",
    bfloorArea: 4,
    cfloorArea: 0,
  },
  {
    occuGroup: "",
    constType: "",
    bfloorArea: 6,
    cfloorArea: 0,
  },
];

console.log(subTotal(items));
```

Answer (score 2):

I would combine map and reduce array functions:

```js
subtotal() {
  return this.items
    .map(({bfloorArea}) => bfloorArea)
    .reduce((a, b) => a + b, 0)
}
```

Using map this way you get a new array containing only the values of bfloorArea, and with reduce you get the total sum of those values.

Hope that helps!

Note: If you need the total of any other property you can just change "bfloorArea" for the property you want. If the property is not in Number type but a string, you can cast it to number when mapping:

```js
.map(({propertyToCast}) => Number(propertyToCast))
```

Comment: I think I should give this a try. Never knew this before Im quite new :). what are those a,b?

Comment: a and b are the previous value and the current value. You can get more info about the reduce function at [_MDN_](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/TypedArray/reduce)

Comment: Also, as people suggested, have in mind that the type of variable you get from an input is not a Number but a String. Cast it as as I suggested on my notes and everything should work smoothly.

Answer (score 1):

It seems to be you are concat string. You will need to convert string to int for your summation.

```
this.items.forEach(element => {
    total += parseInt(element.bfloorArea);
  });
```

Comment: I wonder why that is  - bFloorArea Property is a number , and he starts `total` also with a number. Or is `0` maybe treated differently in this case ?

Comment: input default is string value. `0` i think is because the default hidden item in array

Comment: ah that's why !  OP does not include template, so I just assumend it is using a Number Input.

Answer (score 1):

Another solution without using object destructing could be

```
return this.items.map(item => item.bfloorArea)
    .reduce((prev, current) => prev + parseInt(current,10), 0);
```

Answer (score 1):

### Use correct input type

I want to give a different option. Many suggested to convert the string from the input field, since the default type of an input is `string`.

You didn't include template data so I am just assuming you are in fact using a standard input field like (or something similar)

```
<input v-bind="item.bFloorArea" />
```

In Vue you already have the inbuilt option to automatically typecast the input as a `Number`, therefore your initial code could have worked if you used something like

```
<input v-bind.number="item.bFloorArea" type="number" />
```

Please note the modifier `.number` for Value Binding ( From the docs : https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/forms.html#number )

---

❗ **This would also disallow for the user to input text into a field which clearly needs a number**

Comment: you're right . I did'nt use v-bind with input . I'll use your method from now. Thanks @pascal